# Using static libraries in Swift with CocoaPods fails for Realm

Tags: swift, realm, cocoapods

Since Xcode 9 it is possible to use static libraries by omitting the `use_frameworks!` flag in the Podfile. However, when used with the Pod `RealmSwift` this results in the following error:

```
[!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:

The Swift pod `RealmSwift` depends upon `Realm`, which do not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.
```

Sadly, the proposed solution with `use_modular_headers!` does not work.

Other things I have tried include:

- Using the latest Realm version (3.15.0)
- Use the [Objective C version](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/) and add Swift support, this won't build and give a module not found error in the [RLMSupport.swift](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/Realm/Swift/RLMSupport.swift) file .
- Adding a bridging header for the Objective C version.
- Endless clean, rebuild, Xcode relaunches and Derived Data folder cleaning.

It would not be preferable to circumvent CocoaPods and have this dependency be installed in a separate way, since that would make updating a more complex process. I hope there is a solution that works with CocoaPods, Realm and Swift.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I did the job doing following:

```
pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 3.17', :modular_headers => true
pod 'Realm', '~> 3.17', :modular_headers => true
```

Answer (score 9):

As far as I can tell adding use_modular_headers! to top of Podfile works.

Adding s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES' } to .podspec doesn't work as far as I can tell. (Cocoapods 1.6.0-beta.2)

example:

```
target 'Opportunity' do
    use_modular_headers!

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it wouldn't work. I got the same issue, and I added `use_modular_headers!` following way in the podfile and it worked.

```
target 'Pick Up Lines' do
    use_modular_headers!
    pod 'RealmSwift'
end
```

By the way, before doing any of it, make sure, you set the deployment target of the project as 11.0.

[image]